# How to call isset on escaped variable?

Tags: php, html, smarty

**Goal**:

```
  {if !empty($smarty.get.page|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8')}
  ...
  {/if}
```

**Result:**

```
  ContextErrorException
  Notice: Undefined index: page
```

I can't escape the variable if it doesn't exist, but if I check it's existence I can't escape it.
What can I do here?

Comment: `{if isset($smarty.get.page) AND !empty(...` ?

Comment: @r_a_f Hi, this works but aren't I at risk of injection if I don't escape the `$smarty.get.page` inside the `isset` function?
Like so: `{if isset($smarty.get.page|escape:"html":'UTF-8') AND !empty(...`

Couldn't someone add in the URL `?page='TRUE')&&(TRUE` for example.

Comment: No no, Smarty would be then very dangerous but they aren't. While you not using in your template `eval` function it is save - it is treated as string, you can have in string what you want and it is string not code. If you still not sure, just test it :)

Comment: @r_a_f Ok, so `$smarty.get.` should always return a string and never have it's contents interpreted as code.